# Set multipart upload threshold

Tags: c++, aws-sdk-cpp

In AWS S3 CLI we can set the following parameter:

> multipart_threshold - The size threshold the CLI uses for multipart
>   transfers of individual files.

Can we do something like this in aws cpp sdk client?

Of course, I can set TransferManagerConfiguration bufferSize, but then I would have to use TransferManager. I just want to use S3Client directly.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3Client does not automatically partition the files. Therefore, having such an option would not be very helpful.

S3Client reflects the APIs offered by AWS S3 service. Higher level logic is done in TransferManager.